# add indentation while printing multiline string

Tags: python, python-2.7

This way of applying TAB to the output of print works fine for one line of text. But I need to apply TAB to all lines of my document. Anyone can help?

How can I apply \t to all lines?

```
x=line0\nline2\nline3

print '\t%s'%(x)
```

Comment: Why are you writing new code in Python 2? The language is end-of-life; it has received no updates since the beginning of the year, and never will, not even for security issues. If you're learning, learn Python 3.

Comment: split to multiple strings and join using `'\t\n'`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `replace()` Method:

> The replace() method replaces a specified phrase with another
>   specified phrase.
>
> Note: All occurrences of the specified phrase will be replaced, if
>   nothing else is specified.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> string.replace(oldvalue, newvalue, count)
> ```

```
x='line0\nline2\nline3'

print (x.replace('\n','\t'))
```

output:

```
line0   line2   line3
```

or:

```
x='line0\nline2\nline3'

x=x.replace('\n','\n \t')
print ('\t%s'%(x))
```

output:

```
    line0
    line2
    line3
```

Comment: @daalgoo you're welcome. Im glad that I helped. If this answer is the answer to your question don't forget to upvote or accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.5 or above there is a method to do this try to google it for python2.x

```
x=[line1,line2,line3]
print(x,endline="\t")
```